# Setting range for cells

Tags: excel, vba

How to set range for cells like with formula "102."&H2 and give value 102.1
H2 will give different number after loops

```
Count = 2
For I = 7 To N
If Range("E" & Count) = Range("E" & I) And Range("A" & I) = "102." & [H2] Then
```

Something

This is not working "102." & [H2]

```
 If Range("E" & Count) = Range("E" & I) And Range("A" & I) > 0 Then
```

If i switch with > 0 this works:D

Comment: If you want the value of [H2] you can use `& Range("H2").Value`

Comment: @dzunaa  can you explain what are you trying to compare in your `If` line ? write it in 2 separate lines

Comment: I have in column A cells with fromula =VALUE(IF(B7>0,"102."&$H$2,"0")), so this macro check each cells in cloumn A for value. and if value match he the do some merging of cells. If i have just plain value it works but when I add H2 macro dose not work. Values that i get are like 102.1 or 102.15 or 102.19. 102. is fixed value and other comes from H2 cell

Comment: `Range("A" & I).Text = "102." & [H2]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If Range("E" & Count) = Range("E" & I) And Range("A" & I) = "102." & [H2] Then
```

Something

This is not working with "102." & [H2]

```
 If Range("E" & Count) = Range("E" & I) And Range("A" & I) > 0 Then
```

If i switch with > 0 this works:D